# MS Access can't create a one-to-many relationship between an entity and a bridge table

Tags: ms-access, relational-database

Below is a link to screenshots of the relationship chart. I am trying to create the one-to-many relationship in red, however I am getting the error: 
Microsoft Access cannot create this relationship and enforce referential integrity.

[ms-access can't create this relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtGWG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it means that you have in the table `tblStarredIn` values in `MovieID` column, which don't exist in `[tblMovie].[MovieID]`. Error message should give more details about error, please provide it in full.